# iOS / Swift: Set timeout for opening Streams

Tags: ios, swift, stream, timeout

I am working on an iOS app (Swift 4) that connects to a server via

```
Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: self.host!, port: self.port!, inputStream: &self.inputStream, outputStream: &self.outputStream)
if let instream = self.inputStream, let outstream = self.outputStream {
    instream.delegate = self
    outstream.delegate = self
    instream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
    outstream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
    instream.open()
    outstream.open()
}
```

In case I have a bad internet connection / no connection / server is not reachable for some reason, I want to show the user an error message. This already works but it takes almost a minute until the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out" happens.

Can I somehow reduce the timeout in my app or is this a system-wide timeout that cannot be changed?

The constants for Stream.setProperty do not seam to contain any timeout-related stuff: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/stream#1666775

A workaround I can imagine is to manually schedule a function after X seconds and if the connection is not established then, to cancel it. Is this the best-practice to achieve a custom timeout?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a few threads about this problem I decided to use a Timer that checks for a successful connection after n seconds:

```
Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: self.host!, port: self.port!, inputStream: &self.inputStream, outputStream: &self.outputStream)

if let instream = self.inputStream, let outstream = self.outputStream {
    instream.delegate = self
    outstream.delegate = self
    instream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
    outstream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
    instream.open()
    outstream.open()

    self.connectionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, repeats: false) { _ in
    if !self.instreamReady || !self.outstreamReady {
        self.errorHandler(NetworkingError.Timeout("Timeout \(self.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)s exeeded"))
            self.disconnect()
         }
         self.connectionTimer?.invalidate()
         self.connectionTimer = nil
    }
}
```

Works :)

Comment: What is "connectionTimer"? Kindly mention where did you declare it?

Comment: It is declared in the code snippet: `self.connectionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, repeats: false`

Comment: What is `instreamReady` and `outstreamReady` ?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of information even after comments asked for further explaining.
Not exactly a helpful answer with things missing.

Comment: @simon-h - thanks for the helpful answer.  Not sure why this got down-voted.  The variable names are pretty self-explanatory if you've at least _tried_ wrapping your mind around the problem domain.

Comment: Maybe it's self-explanatory to an expert, but not for me. What is self.disconnect()? How does this stop the connection? I don't even understand at what point is the actual TCP connection made? At getStreamsToHost() or maybe one of the stream.open() calls?

Comment: I've tried to rewrite it to my case as best as I could, it doesn't work, so downvote.

Answer (score 0):

var continue = true
var countin = 0

```
            var inp :InputStream?
            var out :OutputStream?
            let testData = mesaj
            Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: addr, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)
            let stream = out!
            print( stream.streamStatus.rawValue)
            
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                guard continue == true else{
                    timer.invalidate()
                    return
                }
                if (counting == 0){
                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async() {
                        stream.open()
                        var position = 0
                        print( stream.streamStatus.rawValue)
                        while position < testData.count {
                            let length = min(4096, testData.count - position)
                            let amount =  testData[position...].withUnsafeBytes {
                                stream.write($0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!, maxLength: length)
                            }
                            if amount <= 0 {
                                // Error or EOF
                                break
                            }
                            position += amount
                        }
                        stream.close()
                        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                            self.durumTF.text = "Send to PC"
                            self.durumTF.textColor = .blue
                        }
                        continue=false
                    }
                    
                }
                if (counting == 3){
                    print(stream.streamStatus.rawValue)
                    if stream.streamStatus.rawValue == 7 {
                        stream.close()
                        
                        self.durumTF.text = "Couldn't connect to PC"
                        self.durumTF.textColor = .red
                    }
                    if stream.streamStatus.rawValue == 1 {
                        stream.close()
                        
                        self.durumTF.text = "Run server on pc"
                        self.durumTF.textColor = .red
                    }
                    continue = false
                }
                
                counting += 1
                
            }
```